# Elasticsearch Join columns from different index with condition

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I have 2 different indexes in elasticsearch, `indx1` and `indx2` which i have indexed from an SQL Database using river plugin.

```
 indx1

----------
    id  |  Amt
    1      2
    2      3
    3      2   
    1      9 
    2      4 
----------
```

indx 2

```
----------
id   |  Name 
1       Alex
2       Joe
3       MARY


----------
```

I want to create a new index now which calculate the average amount from `indx1` and join everything in a single index.
So the final structure of the index should look like

```
indx_final


----------
id | Name | Avg Amt | Status
1    Alex    5.5      High
2    Joe     3.5      Med
3    Mary    2.0      Low
----------
```

The status is set according to average amount , if Avg amt > 4 , status = high, if avg amt >3, status = Med, If avg amt <2.5 ,status = Low.
Is this possible to do in elasticsearch only? If not possible i would have to do the calculation in SQL and then index the data again.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!